# How to avoid repeating code in if/else statement inside AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I'm trying to do if/else inside Ajax , but as you can see in my script I'm repeating my code and i think it is better way do archive this in one line or doing if/else before Ajax and to be honest i don't know how exactly should i do Can anyone please help me or point me in the right direction! 
Thanks in advance :)

```
function RMAfunction() {
        var model = {
            Serienummer: $("#notavailable").val(),
            SelectedSerieText: $("#ddlSerial option:selected").text(),
            Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
            Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val()
            }
            if (model.Serienummer === 'not available') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        Serienummer: model.Serienummer,
                        Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
                        Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer,
                    },
                    success: function (status) {
                        if (status) {

                            status.Serienummer = model.Serienummer;
                            status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
                            status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Something Wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        Serienummer: model.SelectedSerieText,
                        Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
                        Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer
                    },
                    success: function (status) {
                        if (status) {
                            status.Serienummer = model.SelectedSerieText;
                            status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
                            status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;     
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Something Wrong");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                    }
                });

            }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only change is whether you use the `Serienummer` or `SelectedSerieText` in the properties of `model` based on the original value of `Serienummer`. As such, you can just use a ternary expression where that value is used. Try this:

```js
function RMAfunction() {
  var model = {
    Serienummer: $("#notavailable").val(),
    SelectedSerieText: $("#ddlSerial option:selected").text(),
    Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
    Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val()
  }
  var hasSerieNummer = model.Serienummer === 'not available';

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      Serienummer: hasSerieNummer ? model.Serienummer : model.SelectedSerieText,
      Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
      Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer,
    },
    success: function(status) {
      if (status) {
        status.Serienummer = hasSerieNummer ? model.Serienummer : model.SelectedSerieText;
        status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
        status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;
      } else {
        alert("Something Wrong");
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
    }
  });
}
```

This could potentially be further reduced by using a function in the `model` object to contain the logic which determines which identifier to return:

```js
function RMAfunction() {
  var model = {
    Serienummer: $("#notavailable").val(),
    SelectedSerieText: $("#ddlSerial option:selected").text(),
    Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
    Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val(),
    GetIdentifier: function() {
      return this.Serienummer === 'not available' ? this.Serienummer : this.SelectedSerieText;
    }
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      Serienummer: model.GetIdentifier(), // usage here
      Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
      Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer,
    },
    success: function(status) {
      if (status) {
        status.Serienummer = model.GetIdentifier(); // and here
        status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
        status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;
      } else {
        alert("Something Wrong");
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rory , let me try please , just min :)

Comment: I wonder why the condition is reversed? `!==` instead of `===`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I just personally find it easier to read as the value you test in the ternary is the first returned. Either operator is fine, though.

Comment: mmm... But the logic is reversed. About readability, that would be ok if you also reverse the true : false. in OP question if `model.Serienummer === 'not available'` => `model.Serienummer` is used. In your answer, that logic is reversed.

Comment: I just tried again , when i use like this this.Serienummer !== 'not available' its not going to send serial numbers (if there is serial number)and in db i will get null value , but as @LouysPatriceBessette mentioned i did like  this.Serienummer === 'not available' its going to send serial numbers with value to DB

Comment: So I was right about the logic being reversed... The solution is very good though. ;)

Comment: Apologies to you both. The logic reversal was intentional but I misunderstood its purpose. It made more sense to me that if `Serienummer` was `not available` that you would send the value of `SelectedSerieText` instead, but that was not the case. I've fixed the operators in the question to be accurate now

Answer (score 0):

Try this also correct,

```
var model = {
        Serienummer: $("#notavailable").val(),
        SelectedSerieText: $("#ddlSerial option:selected").text(),
        Kundenavn: $("#Kundenavn").val(),
        Ordrenummer: $("#Ordrenummer").val()
        }
        if (model.Serienummer === 'not available') {
            var data = {
                    Serienummer: model.Serienummer,
                    Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
                    Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer,
                };
        }else{
            var data = {
                Serienummer: model.SelectedSerieText,
                    Kundenavn: model.Kundenavn,
                    Ordrenummer: model.Ordrenummer
            };
        }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("ProcessRequestRMA", "Account")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data);
                success: function (status) {
                    if (status) {
                        if (model.Serienummer === 'not available') {
                            status.Serienummer = model.Serienummer;
                        }else{
                            status.Serienummer = model.SelectedSerieText;
                        }
                            status.Kundenavn = model.Kundenavn;
                            status.Ordrenummer = model.Ordrenummer;
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Something Wrong");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('something went wrong - debug it!');
                }
            });
```